# How to find standard deviation with ONLY sample size?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

So I have this weird math question, that I don't think gives enough information.

Find the standard deviation of the sample proportion for a sample of size 150, when we assume equal probabilities for the wins and losses of a football tournament. Assume also, that the number of outcomes in the population ( N) is very large, essentially infinite.

So I know that finding the standard deviation using sample proportions would be: sq root: pq/n, meaning the equation would be:

square root of: (the mean*(1-mean)/150 )

How would I compute the standard deviation with equal probabilities while the population is infinite?

These are the potential answers:

```
a.  0.12
b.  0.50
c.  0.002
d.  0.25
e.  0.041
```

Comment: If you assume equal probabilities for a win and a loss, what is the numeric value of $p$? What is $q$? What happens when you put those numbers into the formula?

Comment: So, they would both have 1/2 probability, p would be 0.5? thus, 0.5 * (1-/05) / 150 = 0.5 * 0.5/ 150 = .25/150 = 0.0016666, I guess that could round to the 0.002?

Comment: You’re on the right track. Don’t forget the square root.